ASP.NET - Google authentication, is there a way to get customization authentication flow?
I tried adding / customizing authentication flow of Google OAuth2 in ASP.NET Web API and heavn't found how to handle it in the app in order to register an OAuth2 user and generate a JWT tokens for it.
Any advice / examples?
